# How to get time taken coverage report for each test cases in jest

Tags: jestjs, report, istanbul

With this below script, we can collect time taken report per suite but not every test case.

`jest --runInBand __tests__/*tests.ts --json --verbose --outputFile=testout.json`

So is there a way we can check the elapsed time per each test execution?

[image]